# android vertical scroller / pager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I need to be able to flip vertically through a set of images. i've looked at using `ViewPager`, but it seems to only support horizontal paging.

I also looked at `Gallery`, but i also don't see a way to page vertically. and regardless, it's deprecated in favor of `HorizontalScrollView` which obviously won't work.

it occurred that i might use a `ListView`, but it won't snap to pages, nor could i easily size each list item to about the size of a "page".

are there any solutions for vertical scrolling / paging?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: i did not. i ended up using a list view and fitting the image to width. it's not what i wanted but the best i could do without authoring my own complex paging widget.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation of a [vertical ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) from Jake Wharton. You may want to take a look at that.

It's easy to integrate:

```
<com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: thanks, yes i contacted the author he told me (in so many words) that it's deprecated and in favor of the official view pager, and pointed to an issue he failed for the official pager to support vertical orientations.